solve version conflict issue when installing DRF react project
My objective is to create DRF + reactjs web project which includes SSO. Having a background in python but not in reactjs, I started with this video on youtube. link. It is a very useful resource but the issue i am facing currently is the web page would not start without an error. I am guessing it is a version conflict issue as it was made 3 years ago. How to resolve this issue ?
ERROR:
Uncaught runtime errors ReactCurrentActQueue$1 is undefined
ensureRootIsScheduled@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:52408:15
scheduleUpdateOnFiber@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:52319:30
updateContainer@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:55172:30
> ./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js/legacyCreateRootFromDOMContainer/<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:55771:26
flushSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:52891:18
legacyCreateRootFromDOMContainer@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:55770:18
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:55792:16
render@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:55857:14
> ./src/index.js@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1740:40
options.factory@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:67570:31
__webpack_require__@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:67033:32
> @http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68152:56
> @http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68154:12


To highlight an issue, I tried downgrading axios and inspite of downgrading to version 0.20.0 it still shows 1.6.8 on command
npm view axios version



package.json
{
  "name": "blogapi",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}



